# How to update a referenced object with PATCH request in spring data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have 2 connected entities: Project and System. The mapping looks like that in Project class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "system_id")
@NotNull
private System system;
```

I'm trying to use spring data-rest to implement the basic rest API for projects. Simple stuff like GET or updating simple properties works great. But this query causes difficulties:

```
PATCH /api/projects/1 HTTP/1.1
{
  "name": "Name2",
  "system": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

I want this query to change the name and to change the linked system object and can't find a way how to do it. I understand, there's possibility to update links with an extra query as descibed here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships. But I need to preserve the legacy API interface, so I need to make that interface work.
The error being thrown is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.company.resourceapi.entities.Project was altered from 3 to 1
```

**Upd.** To clarify: before the update the Project is

```
id: 1,
name: "Name1",
system_id: 2
```

after PATCH request I want to see

```
id: 1,
name: "Name2",
system_id: 1
```

Comment: I've tried overriding jackson's deserializer, spring's repository, but the problem persists: if system id is the same - no error. If the id is different - the error on Hibernate's flush.

Comment: What's happening with existing refferenced object ?

Comment: @Eklavya as I understand, when the Project go to the level of repository, the linked System object gets fetched from the db, but the id from the request is kept. Even if I override Project's system, Hibernate tries to save the old one and it causes the error.

Comment: First clear what you want with existing referenced object and new referenced object, both preserve or new only, if both then what will be the reference for the old one

Comment: @Eklavya I update Project and want to update the linked System object. I want to update only the link in Project. Actually your question gave me an idea: I can manually detach the old System object in custom repository. Though this solution is quite inelegant, I hope there's a better way.

Comment: Still not clear, please read my last comment. And yes you can do that

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this not very elegant solution:
I override `save` method in repository like that:

```
public class ProjectRepositoryImpl implements CustomSaveRepo<Project> {
    @Autowired
    private SystemRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Project save(Project entity) {
        // entity.system has the id from the request, in the same time it's managed entity.
        if (entity.getSystem() != null) {
            Long sysId = entity.getSystem().getId();
            if (sysId != null) {
                em.detach(entity.getSystem());
                System system = repository.findById(sysId)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
                entity.setSystem(system );
            }
        }
        entity.setUpdatedAt(new Date());

        em.persist(entity);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Would be grateful is someone shared with me a better solution.